# Bar graph displaying values from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a class that generates a bar graph displaying the data from ArrayList 'variables' as the bars, and using the labels from ArrayList 'labels' on the x-axis.

Currently, all this displays is the values from the add method in BarChartComponent, which were used as filler values to make sure the bars were being created.

Does anybody know how I would edit this code to correctly display the bar graph?

Thanks

Code:

BarGraph class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BarGraph {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private ArrayList<Double> variables; //for storing data for bar graph
    private ArrayList<String> labels; // for storing names of x, y axes

public BarGraph(int aWidth, int aHeight, ArrayList<String> labels, ArrayList<Double> variables) {
    this.width = aWidth;
    this.height = aHeight;
    this.variables = variables;
    this.labels = labels;

}

public void add(double value, String X) {
    variables.add(value);
    labels.add(X);
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
    int i = 0;
    double max = 0;

    for (Double wrapper : variables)
        if (max < wrapper)
            max = wrapper;

    int xwidth = width - 1;
    int yheight = height - 1;

    int xleft = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < variables.size(); i++) {
        int xright = width * (i + 1) / variables.size();
        int barWidth = xwidth / variables.size();
        int barHeight = (int) Math.round(yheight * variables.get(i) / max);

        Rectangle bar =
                new Rectangle(xleft, yheight - barHeight,
                        barWidth, barHeight);
        g2.draw(bar);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);

        xleft = xright;
    }

   }
}
```

BarChartComponent class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class BarChartComponent extends JComponent {
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("Oil");
    labels.add("Gas");
    labels.add("Nuclear");
    labels.add("Coal");
    labels.add("Combined Cycle Gas Turbines (W)");
    labels.add("Irish Interconnector (W)");
    labels.add("Open Cycle Gas Turbines");
    labels.add("Wind");
    labels.add("French Interconnector (W)");
    labels.add("Piped Storage (W)");
    labels.add("Dutch Interconnector (W)");
    labels.add("Hydroelectric Power (W)");
    labels.add("Solar PV");
    labels.add("East-West Interconnector (W)");
    ArrayList<Double> variables = new ArrayList<>();
    GraphAverages data = new GraphAverages();
    variables.add(0, data.averageCCGT2016);
    variables.add(1, data.averageCCGT2017);
    variables.add(2, data.averageCoal2016);
    variables.add(3, data.averageCoal2017);
    variables.add(4, data.averageDutch2016);
    variables.add(5, data.averageDutch2017);
    variables.add(6, data.averageEw2016);
    variables.add(7, data.averageEw2017);
    variables.add(8, data.averageFrench2016);
    variables.add(9, data.averageFrench2017);
    variables.add(10, data.averageHydro2016);
    variables.add(11, data.averageHydro2017);
    variables.add(12, data.averageIrish2016);
    variables.add(13, data.averageIrish2017);
    variables.add(14, data.averageNuclear2016);
    variables.add(15, data.averageNuclear2017);
    variables.add(16, data.averageOCGT2016);
    variables.add(17, data.averageOCGT2017);
    variables.add(18, data.averageOil2016);
    variables.add(19, data.averageOil2017);
    variables.add(20, data.averageOther2016);
    variables.add(21, data.averageOther2017);
    variables.add(22, data.averagePumped2016);
    variables.add(23, data.averagePumped2017);
    variables.add(24, data.averageSolar2016);
    variables.add(25, data.averageSolar2017);
    variables.add(26, data.averageWind2016);
    variables.add(27, data.averageWind2017);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    BarGraph c = new BarGraph(getWidth(), getHeight(), labels, variables);
    c.add(1.1, "Oil");
    c.add(3.6, "Gas");
    c.add(4.0, "Coal");
    c.add(3.7, "filler");
    c.add(2.1, "filler");
    c.add(2.7, "filler");
    c.add(2.6, "filler");

    /* TODO:
    Graph details:
     - Shows two bars for each type of power produced, one for 2016 and other for 2017
    Label Graph
    Implement data from CSV
    Colour bars in - Different colour for each year EG red/blue


     */


    c.draw(g2);

}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure your data variable in paintComponent(...) actually contains any values? Have you tried to debug this to see what happens in the draw(...) method?

Comment: Can you explain how I would go about doing that?

Comment: I don't know what development environment you're using so it's hard to advice on that. But wether it is an IDE or a text editor and the command line you use I think you should learn how the debugger works, it's one of the best tools available for a programmer.